# Forcing an input in python

Tags: python, input, forcing

I am trying to make a graphical interface (with tkinter) on an existing python project which work well in command line.
The command line used the function `Input()` to get parameter from the keybord, but now I want to interface this things with my graphical interface. Then, when I push the button (on my interface), I want to input the selected value from the interface to the `Input()` method, but I don't know how to do that, and even if it's possible. I tried with `sys.stdin` but it's not working.
If someone have any idea, let me know,
thank you :)

Comment: Try grabbing input from the terminal and using that in the interface. There are ways to get text input in a GUI, but it's complicated.

Comment: Your code should be a function which accepts an argument. You can take the value for that argument either from `input()`, or from a GUI. But in the end you should pass it to your function like `foo(val)`. `foo` doesn't change, only where `val` comes from changes.

Comment: Thanks for your responds,
@PeterNielsen, which kind of function could I use to do that (grab input from terminal) ?

Comment: I'll give an answer.

Comment: @deceze I wanted to do that at the begining but I need the blocking state from ```Input()``` to have the information from the player. And also how can I stop this blocking state from ```Input()```  when the information are becomming from the GUI ?

Comment: You will probably need to restructure your code a lot for it to be adaptable to a GUI app, if you’re *relying* on `input`, that’s a bad place to start for a GUI. Look into *MVC* separation, that’s exactly made for this case. You want to exchange the *View* (CLI to GUI) and *Controller* (CLI input to GUI events), while keeping your *Model* (the game logic) the same.

Comment: ok, I didn't wanted to restructure everything because that's the only input of the game, but I think that's the better way yes. Thank you :) 
For my question, so you thinks that's not possible to fill ```Input()``` function by code with another thread as explain downstairs

Answer (score 0):

uhm, i think it's not gonna work for what I wanted to do

This is an example of my idea, let me explain again :
I have an `Input()`  function in my game thread, and I want to fill it by 2 differents ways :

-directly with the terminal

-with my interface by using the submit button : this button call a function where I want to fill the `Input()`  by the selected value on the GUI

there is an exemple of my code :

````
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def submitEvent():
    print('Submit is pushed')
    # --> fill the Input() with the value of the combobox ( listeCombo.get() )

def gameThread():
    input("give a number between 1 and 4")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
x = threading.Thread(target=gameThread)
x.start()
list=['1', '2', '3', '4']
combolist = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list)
submitButton = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submitEvent)
combolist.grid(column=1, row=1)
submitButton.grid(column=1, row=2)
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Not a good practice to use `input` while using GUI, using `Entry` is the right way of getting user input, usually.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```py
global somevariable
somevariable = input('prompt: ')
```

And then to call it later:

```py
thingneededforgui = somevariable
```

That should work. I use such things when designing pgzero games.